# I want to animate a factory treadmill with a dartboard on it. Can i parent the dartboard to each plate so it moves exactly the same around the curve?

Tags: animation, modifiers, curve-modifier

So i animated the plates so that they move around the curve. I have added an array modifier and a curve modifier! I want to have one dartboard for every plate so that they move exactly like the plates with the bending in the curve. I dont know how to parent it that way. I tried to add the array and curve modifier to the dartboard aswell but it didnt work and i think there is an easier and cleaner way.

Can u help me to make this one animation and not two seperate ones?

Thanks :D

Link to the Blender File

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your .blend file to give it a try ? You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Comment: I just did it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.1)*

*NB: Original objects were appended from a higher version Blender file.*
[image: Treadmill & Dartboard]

**Approach:**

- For the dartboard to remain flat when following the curve, it can not have the *Curve* modifier. It has to be instanced by another object having the *Curve* modifier. So it has to be child of this instancer.
- On the contrary for the plate to deform along the curve, it must have the *Curve* modifier. It must also have enough subdivisions to match the curve local radius. So it can not be the dartboard instancer because it has more than one vertex and more than one face, whereas a single dartboard per plate is expected. Instantiation is done after modifiers are applied. So starting from a single face plane with a *Subdivision* modifier in not an option.
- As a conclusion, the dartboard and the plate can not be parented. These have to be siblings, children of a third object that is controlling their relative position.

**Procedure:**

- The *Plate* has three modifiers:

  - *Solidify* to make it tick ;
  - *Array* to duplicate it six times ;
  - *Curve* to position and to deform along the curve the resulting necklace of copies.
- The *Circle* has no modifier. It is the child of the *Controller*.
- The *Controller* is a simple plane, instancing on *Faces* its single child. It is not showed in Viewport and Render. It has two modifiers:

  - *Array* to duplicate it six times ;
  - *Curve* to position along the curve the resulting necklace of copies.
- All modifiers being deactivated, the *Plate* and the *Controller* must share the same origin position. This makes copies synchronized along the curve.
- The parent of the *Plate* and of the *Controller* is an *Empty*. It is translated along a single world axis (here Y) during the animation:

  - So the *Plate* and the *Controller* are translated to follow the *Empty*.
  - So the distance between their origin and the curve origin is increased.
  - So their copies are shifted from the curve starting point.

**Resources:** [image]

**Result:**

[image: Animation]

Comment: Hey thank you very much for this long answer! But i still have one question, how can i parent the Dartboard to the controller when i can only select the origin piece of the controller because the other ones are the duplicated ones because of the array modifier ? Do you know what i mean ?

Comment: You are welcome. If I understand well your question, you can switch off modifiers, one at a time or all of them, with the "monitor/screen" icon in each modifier header (next to the name). This way, switching off the Array, you should be able to pick the controller in the 3D viewport. Or more easily, you can just make the selection in the outliner. There you don't have copies, only the "original" element.